# SQL JOIN query not displaying anything- PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing a sql query but it is not returning any data from the tables. I am not sure why, I have changed from `INNER` to `LEFT` but no luck. I have revised the query several times but i cant find an issue. Any thoughts of why I am not getting anything displayed?

[TABLE STRUCTURE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/table_structure.php)

[TABLE CREATE QUERY](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/query_create.php)

**PHP**

```
$query = ("SELECT  class.class_name, class.class_caption, class.class_credit_hours, class.class_description, faculty_fname, faculty_lname
            FROM class
            LEFT JOIN section 
            ON class.id = section.class_id
            LEFT JOIN faculty 
            ON faculty.id = section.faculty_id OR faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
            LEFT JOIN faculty_titles
            ON faculty_titles.faculty_id = faculty.id
            LEFT JOIN faculty_education
            ON faculty_education.faculty_id = faculty.id 
            LEFT JOIN major_class_br
            ON major_class_br.class_id = class.id
            LEFT JOIN major_minor 
            ON major_class_br.major_minor_id = major_minor.id
            LEFT JOIN sched_sect_br 
            ON sched_sect_br.section_id =  section.id
            LEFT JOIN schedule
            ON schedule.id = sched_sect_br.schedule_id
            LEFT JOIN semester
            ON semester.id = schedule.semester_id
            LEFT JOIN office_hours
            ON schedule.id = office_hours.schedule_id AND faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id       
                 ");
      //execute query
      $result = mysql_query($query);

     if ($result){

    $totalhours = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
    {  
        print "<b>" . $row['class_name'] . "</b><br>";
        print $row['class_caption'] . "<br>";
        print $row ['class_credit_hours'] . "hrs. <br>";
            print $row ['faculty_lname'] . "hrs. <br>";
            print $row ['faculty_fname'] . "hrs. <br>";
        print $row['class_description'] . "<br>";      
        print "------------------------------<br />";
        $totalhours += $row['class_credit_hours']; 
    }   
    }

    print "<p>Total hours for Major: " . $totalhours . ".</p>";
```

**Desired display:**

```
Computer Programming I
CP1000
4
James Doe
This course offers introduction to programming.
```

**UPDATE: The issue was found here but I am not sure why**

```
ON faculty.id = section.faculty_id OR faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
```

Comment: Your tables all have the necessary rows, yes?

Comment: Your `SELECT` list only draws from `class` and `faculty` and you have no `WHERE` clause. What is the reason for all the other `JOIN`s beyond `class -> section -> faculty`?

Comment: Looks to me like your `class` table is empty.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Its an example, I will pull more information from other tables but didnt want to have an overwhelming query size.

Comment: @charliecodex23 - You provided table create query and table structure. If you provide table data insert query too then we can check problem in your query very fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy the SQL, go to MySQL admin, execute the SQL there and see if it returns any results.
- Remove all the JOIN and execute again, you should see at least something
- Add the JOIN one by one
- Try to identify which JOIN resulted in no rows being returned
- Check the left and right hand side of that join and ensure there actually are valid data to join

Alternatively use OUTER JOIN